# Composer not autoloading file outsider vendor

Tags: php, composer-php

Using composer's autoloader the below instance of application triggers the autoloader

```
$app = new Application();
```

While the instantiation of Application as a parameter does not trigger the autoloader to load that class. To note the below code loads the Server class but not the Application class.

```
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
```

The Application class is located outside of vendor and this is how I specify it in the composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src"
    }
  }
}
```

The namespaces that I use are as below

```
use App\Application;
use Stin\Http\Server;
```

Comment: what about your namespaces?

Comment: @meda  I have them I will include that in to the question so that you can see.

Comment: Do you get any errors

Comment: @meda I get no errors just a blank page. So I then debugged and stepped through to the point where it autoloads, and it only loads the Server class, and doesn't even call the Application class. If it did it would also have gone to the constructor of Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$app = new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config');
$server = new Server($app);
```

I cannot really explain why nested new objects would not work, It seems to be memory related, or maybe a php limitation.

But I can tell you it is not about the autoload, here is the proof

```
class a {

}


class b {
 public function __construct($yo)
 {
     echo $yo;
 }
}

new a(new b('hello')); //does not work

$b = new b('yo');
new a($b);//work
```

Comment: I tried that before and it works, but I don't understand why the in parameter class instantiation isn't working. That was actually the reason that I ask this question because it confused me so much.

Comment: @m..I expanded on my post, If you ever find out the reason let me know  it is interesting

Comment: @m.. the answer is this issue has been fixed int the latest version of PHP 7.1  here is a demo https://3v4l.org/0SNga

Comment: Thanks man. It works flawlessly with 7.1. PHP versions did not come to mind. It seems weird because I thought that was something that could normally be done. Nice to see PHP is finally starting to evolve for the better.